# How to populate dynamic form in Flask with dictionary?

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, flask

I have dynamic form:

```
class CollectionRequestParamForm(Form):
    param_human_name = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    param_request_name = StringField()


class CollectionRequestParamCombinedForm(FlaskForm):
    params = FieldList(FormField(CollectionRequestParamForm), min_entries=1)
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

After the user has sent form i add dict like this in my collection (I use MongoDB):

```
example_form = {
    'Имя': 'name',
    'Возраст': 'age'
}
```

Ofcourse, if its needed i can change my data structure, for example:

```
example_form = [
    {'param_human_name': 'Имя', 'param_request_name': 'name'},
    {'param_human_name': 'Возраст', 'param_request_name': 'age'},
]
```

And now, how i can populate my form with data from my dict? I tired:

```
collection_request_params_form = CollectionRequestParamCombinedForm()
i = 0
for key, value in example_form.items():
    collection_request_params_form.params.data[i]['param_human_name'] = key
    collection_request_params_form.params.data[i]['param_request_name'] = value
    ## Or...
    collection_request_params_form.data['params'][i]['param_human_name'] = key
    collection_request_params_form.data['params'][i]['param_request_name'] = value
    i += 1
```

And this don't work :(

How i can populate my form with dict?

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.. This question on russian stackoverflow community: [This question on russian stackoverflow community with images](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775918/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F-python-flask)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, i'm not sure if this will work or not.

```
i=0
for ex in example_form:
  for key,value in ex.items():
    collection_request_params_form.params.data[i]['param_human_name'] = key
    collection_request_params_form.params.data[i]['param_request_name'] = value
     ## Or...
    collection_request_params_form.data['params'][i]['param_human_name'] = key
    collection_request_params_form.data['params'][i]['param_request_name'] = value
    i+=1
```

If this didn't work, can you explan the **data** of the next line?

```
collection_request_params_form.params.data[i]['param_human_name'] = key
```

Comment: Your solution not work :( For example: human_name is 'User Name', request_name is 'u_name'